# Is it possible to save a InfoPath view to word document

Tags: infopath, word

I am trying to save a view in InfoPath 2010 form to word document. Is it possible to do so? Are there any options to do so? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but it's not user friendly. It's a good method if your looking to create a Record of an InfoPath form to a Records management system.

Follow these steps:

1. Open your InfoPath form in Design view
2. Copy your main view and Create a New View (call it Record)
3. Save and publish your form
4. Export the Source Files into a folder on your desktop
5. Delete all but the Records.xml
6. Now open a completed InfoPath.xml file in Word (it would look awful)
7. There should be a tab on the right-hand side called xml data views, click Browse and open the Record.xml
8. It will now look like your InfoPath form

Hope this is what you wanted!